# Can interior set or exterior set be empty?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to prove or disprove  that if $X$ is a boundary of $S$ in $R$, then every ball $B(x)$ contains both interior point of $S$ and exterior point of $S$.

I'm trying to think of counterexample, and one thing came up in mind that if $IntS$ is empty,  does that mean every point of $R$ is exterior set and no boundary point exists?

And can anyone help me with the proof ?

Comment: What is the definition of boundary?

Comment: Definition of boundary given in my textbook is that it is neither exterior nor interior

Comment: If $S$ has empty interior, then every point of $S$ is a boundary point.

Comment: Hence, point $x$ is in the boundary of $S$ if every open neighbourhood of $x$ (in the usual topology of ${\mathbb R}$, every open ball with center in $x$) contains at least one point from $S$ and at least one point from the complement of $S$. It is possible that the interior of $S$ is empty, or that the exterior is empty, or both are empty. Think about ${\mathbb Q}$.

Comment: Janko Bracic, thank you for ur comment. Are you saying that there is no counterexample to above statement? If x is a boundary point of S, then every ball of x must have both interior and exterior?

Comment: You need examples. Think of $\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Let we have the real number topological space $(R,τ_1)$ 
The set $Q$ is a subset of $R$ and $Ext(Q)=Int(Q)=$empty set